# GRUB geom error trying to install Linux

Tags: linux, installation, grub

Tried installing Linux (Red Hat 5) along with Windows 7. I created a new partition (10 GB in size) and used it for the Linux installation. After install, I was getting `GRUB geom error` and my system wasn't booting.

After a few tries I had to format my entire hard disk and run **fixmbr** which came up with the following warning message:

> A new MBR will be created and some of the partition may become inaccessible

Now, even though I have gotten back Windows, the Linux partition is not at all visible. (Seems like the warning message has become a reality as that partition looks like has become inaccessible.)

My new hard disk capacity has also reduced by 10 GB and it is not showing up using any software.

How can I recover that inaccessible partition?

#### Edit

I tried **fdisk** via Linux Rescue disk. Got an error 22, the details as follows:

```
Command (m for help): w 
The partition table has been altered! 
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table. 
WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 22: Invalid argument 
The kernel still uses the old table. 
The new table will be used at the next reboot.
```

No luck booting in Windows.

Comment: "red hat 5"? RHEL 5?

Answer (score 1):

Boot up with a Linux live or rescue disk, run `fdisk`, and delete the 10GB partition from there.

Answer (score 0):

Super Grub is awesome. It'll fix your boot loader.
http://www.supergrubdisk.org/

Burn the ISO to a disk, stick it in your drive, reboot, boot from disk, follow the instructions. Works like a charm. :)